# Flask, flask-login - I don't get it

Tags: python, flask

I have a mysql table with users and roles and I have a login page. It works. But, I don't get how to look up a user from a database.

1) Here is my User class and login form

```
class User(UserMixin):
    def __init__(self, email, password, org_role, user_role, id, active=True):
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.org_role = org_role
        self.user_role = user_role
        self.id = id
        self.active = active
    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True
    def is_active(self):
        return True
    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False
    def get_id(self):
        return unicode(self.id)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % (self.email)


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return USERS.get(int(id))


@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if request.method == "POST" and form.validate():
        if form.email.data + form.password.data in USER_NAMES:
            remember = request.form.get("remember", "no") == "yes"
            if login_user(USER_NAMES[form.email.data + form.password.data], remember=remember):
                flash("Logged in!")
                return redirect(request.args.get("next") or url_for("index"))
            else:
                flash(u"Sorry, but you could not log in.")
        else:
            flash(u"Invalid email/password.")
    return render_template("login.html", title = 'Sign In', form = form)
```

2) Here is what I don't understand.

I have this code:

```
USERS={}
for i,nn in enumerate(userlist):
    USERS[i+1]=User(nn['email'],nn['password'],nn['org_role'],nn['user_role'],int(nn['user_id']))
USER_NAMES = dict((u.email + u.password, u) for u in USERS.itervalues())
```

When I start the application, I have a mysql query that populates all of the allowed `USERS`.

I tried to follow the docs from flask-login but they dont show an example to do a lookup for users from a database. Only from a prepopulated list of users. If I update a user in a table, it's not picked up unless I restart the server.

This really makes no sense. Any guidance on how to lookup a user from a mysql database and add then to the User class will be great.

Below is my code for getting all users:

```
def getUsers():
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host=db_host,user=db_username,passwd=db_password,db=db_database)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    #query = """SELECT * from rtb_users WHERE email='%s' and password='%s'""" % (email,user_password)
    query = """SELECT * from rtb_users"""
    cursor.execute(query)

    userlist = []
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        user_id = row[0]
        email = row[1]
        password = row[2]
        first_name = row[3]
        last_name = row[4]
        org_role = row[5]
        user_role = row[6]

        temp = {'user_id':user_id,'email':email,'password':password,'first_name':first_name,'last_name':last_name,'org_role':org_role,'user_role':user_role}
        userlist.append(temp)
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    return userlist
userlist = getUsers()
```

Comment: Post your MYSQL query to populate the users. are you calling `g.db.commit()`? Are you closing your cursor?

Comment: Why does `is_authenticated()` return `True`? Also, use SQLAlchemy to wrap your database operations. I have a suspicion that the problem is with your query.

Comment: THe code works.  That is not the issue.  Issue is that when the app loads, it keeps the users in memory.  If a user logs in, it checks the  USERS to see if the username and password match.  But if I add a new user, the user list does not refresh.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You can check the database for a user just as easily as you can check  a dict for a user. Just query the database each time you need to check for a user.

Comment: You are saying "But if I add a new user, the user list does not refresh". How are you adding a new user ? Directly through mysql OR through the front end in your flask app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply access the database each time you need to load a user:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return get_user(id)

def get_user(user_id):

    # TODO: Return None on ValueError
    user_id = int(user_id)

    conn = MySQLdb.connect(...etc...)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    user = cursor.fetchone("SELECT * FROM rtb_users WHERE ID = %s", (user_id, ))

    conn.close()

    try:
        # A simpler way to map row names to row values in a dictionary
        user = dict(zip(cursor.description, user))
        user = User(user['email'],
                        user['password'],
                        user['org_role'],
                        user['user_role'],
                        int(user['user_id']))
    except MySQLdb.Error:
        user = None

    return user
```

Eventually, you will most likely want caching on the `get_user` function (to avoid adding a database call for every single connection made to your server), but for testing, this *should* work.

Comment: I have a feeling that this will quickly exhaust mysql open connections.

Comment: *Chuckles* - @BurhanKhalid - good point - I've updated it to at least close the connection :-)

Comment: Thanks but in the login, How do I call?  if a user enters a username and a password, I have to lookup in a database and if true, auth, if not then fail.  Should get_user take get_user(email,password)?